# Play file upload : warn: Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received

Tags: scala, playframework

Experimenting with the "Play Scala File Upload Example", I've got the following warning:

```
[warn] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received... Note that the connection will be closed after this response. Also, many clients will not read early responses! Consider only issuing this response after the request data has been completely read!
```

Is there any way to avoid this warning ?

The full source code is available here: https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-fileupload-example/tree/2.6.x

This is the detail of the file upload handling request:

```
  type FilePartHandler[A] = FileInfo => Accumulator[ByteString, FilePart[A]]

  /**
   * Uses a custom FilePartHandler to return a type of "File" rather than
   * using Play's TemporaryFile class.  Deletion must happen explicitly on
   * completion, rather than TemporaryFile (which uses finalization to
   * delete temporary files).
   *
   * @return
   */
  private def handleFilePartAsFile: FilePartHandler[File] = {
    case FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
      val path: Path = Files.createTempFile("multipartBody", "tempFile")
      val fileSink: Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.toPath(path)
      val accumulator: Accumulator[ByteString, IOResult] = Accumulator(fileSink)
      accumulator.map {
        case IOResult(count, status) =>
          logger.info(s"count = $count, status = $status")
          FilePart(partName, filename, contentType, path.toFile)
      }
  }

  /**
   * A generic operation on the temporary file that deletes the temp file after completion.
   */
  private def operateOnTempFile(file: File) = {
    val size = Files.size(file.toPath)
    logger.info(s"size = ${size}")
    Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath)
    size
  }

  /**
   * Uploads a multipart file as a POST request.
   *
   * @return
   */
  def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData(handleFilePartAsFile)) { implicit request =>
    val fileOption = request.body.file("name").map {
      case FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file) =>
        logger.info(s"key = ${key}, filename = ${filename}, contentType = ${contentType}, file = $file")
        val data = operateOnTempFile(file)
        data
    }

    Ok(s"file size = ${fileOption.getOrElse("no file")}")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Play that I just fixed [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/9077). It only happens when you make chunked requests. It can be worked around by using Play's Netty server backend instead of Akka HTTP.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as @Eric, and I'm not moving to v2.8 yet ...I would to know what you means by *Play's Netty server backend instead of Akka HTTP* ? Can you add an exemple ?

Comment: The bug was fixed in 2.6.22 and 2.7.1, which were both released over a year ago. You don't need to upgrade to 2.8. If you search for "play netty server" in Google, the top result is https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/NettyServer, which explains exactly how to switch with code examples.

Comment: I'm using play 2.6.3 :(

Comment: So upgrade to 2.6.25, the two releases should be at a minimum binary compatible, but the Play team is quite careful to ensure they don't break things in patch fixes. Not only will you get a fix to this bug, you'll get a whole host of other bug fixes including security vulnerability fixes. Seriously, Play 2.6.3 was released almost 3 years ago, not upgrading a service with patch fixes over that time could be described as negligent.

Comment: Ok thanks, i’ll try to speak with the team responsable for uprading play