# Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received

Tags: servlets, playframework

I am uploading a file with Play Framework, but I am getting this warning:

> [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(play-dev-mode)] Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received... Note that the connection will be closed after this response. Also, many clients will not read early responses! Consider only issuing this response after the request data has been completely read!

I really don't know, if this is a warning to be worried, or I need take care on my code implementation.

This is my actual code to upload a file:

```
public Result imageUpload(){
    try{
         MultipartFormData<File> body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
          FilePart<File> picture = body.getFile("file");
          String fileName = picture.getFilename();
          String contentType = picture.getContentType();
            File file = picture.getFile();
          System.out.println(picture);
          System.out.println(fileName);
          System.out.println(contentType);
          System.out.println(file);


    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return ok();
}
```

Do you think is there something wrong with this?

Comment: Which version of play?

Comment: Hi Frederic, version 2.6.3

Comment: Are you sure that that's the action that's being invoked here, and it's not some other action? Do you always get that warning? It sounds like it could be a bug in Play.

Comment: Is it happening on every request with every browser? Or only occasionally? It's possibly a badly formatted body.

Comment: I am using IONIC as the front end, so when i send from the browser or phone emulator I have the same response.

Comment: I am trying to upload an image, and every time i uploaded the image, i get the same exact warning. I dont know if it is a warning or i need to be worried about it. How do i need to mitigate this risk?

Comment: You should `return ok()` after completion of the file upload. I wish Lightbend gives proper examples

Comment: related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45732520/8325761) post it's a play bug